# Simplifying batch backup script

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, simplify

I've made this script (minus all my ECHO for your readability) to backup certain user folders to an external device. It's working flawlessly, but I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas as to how I could simplify it (eg. more 'clever').

I'm new to this site and coding. Please bear with me!

All help appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET driveLetter=%~d0

:CHOOSE

SET /P CHOOSE=Are you sure you want to continue [Y/N]? 

IF /I "%CHOOSE%" == "Y" GOTO :chooseYes
IF /I "%CHOOSE%" == "N" GOTO :chooseNo

GOTO :CHOOSE

:chooseYes

MKDIR %driveLetter%\Desktop
MKDIR %driveLetter%\Documents
MKDIR %driveLetter%\Favorites
MKDIR %driveLetter%\Pictures
MKDIR %driveLetter%\Downloads

TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL

ROBOCOPY %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ %driveLetter%\Desktop /E /COPYALL /ZB /MT:20 /XJ /R:2 /W:5
ROBOCOPY %USERPROFILE%\Documents\ %driveLetter%\Documents /E /COPYALL /ZB /MT:20 /XJ /R:2 /W:5
ROBOCOPY %USERPROFILE%\Favorites\ %driveLetter%\Favorites /E /COPYALL /ZB /MT:20 /XJ /R:2 /W:5
ROBOCOPY %USERPROFILE%\Pictures\ %driveLetter%\Pictures /E /COPYALL /ZB /MT:20 /XJ /R:2 /W:5
ROBOCOPY %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\ %driveLetter%\Downloads /E /COPYALL /ZB /MT:20 /XJ /R:2 /W:5

CLEANMGR /C: /SAGERUN:65535 /SETUP

TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL

DEFRAG /C /H /V /W

PAUSE

EXIT    

:chooseNo 

TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK >NUL
```

Best regards.

Comment: You should most likely move over to [CodeReview.SE] (although I am not sure if they are talking about batch as well...). As long as your code works, it is not correctly placed on SO.

Comment: This post suits better on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, don't repeat yourself

```dos
:chooseYes

    for %%a in ( Desktop Documents Favorites Pictured Downloads ) do (
        robocopy "%userprofile%\%%a" "%driveLetter%\%%a" /E /COPYALL /ZB /MT:20 /XJ /R:2 /W:5
    )

    CLEANMGR /C: /SAGERUN:65535 /SETUP
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
    DEFRAG /C /H /V /W
    PAUSE
    EXIT
```

note: the `mkdir` has been supressed as the `robocopy` command will create the target folder

Comment: Thanks a lot, a loop like this was exactly what I was looking for!